# Vector doesn't live long enough until I clone it

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I don't understand why `v` doesn't live long enough in snippet `(2)`, but it works in the other cases. If I don't need to `clone` the variable in `(1)`, why do I need to clone it to get the second case to work?

```
fn main() {
    // (1)
    let v = make_vec().unwrap();
    let m = v.last();

    // (2) v doesn't live long enough!
    let m = make_vec()
        .and_then(|v| v.last());

    // (3) Fixed!
    let m = make_vec()
        .and_then(|v| v.last().cloned());
}

fn make_vec() -> Option<Vec<u32>> {
    Some(vec![1, 2, 3])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, ownership of the `Option` passes from `make_vec` to the `unwrap` call. `unwrap` *consumes* the Option and returns the `Vec`, whose ownership passes to the variable `v`. The call to `last` returns a reference into `v`.

In the second case, ownership of the `Option` passes from `make_vec` to the call to `and_then`. `and_then` *consumes* the `Option`, and passes ownership of the `Vec` to the closure. The call to `last` in the closure returns a reference into the `Vec`. Since the closure owned the vector but is now finished running, the `Vec` will be dropped. The reference into the `Vec` would point to memory that is no longer valid, thus the compilation error.

In the third case, ownership of the `Option` passes from `make_vec` to the call to `and_then`. `and_then` *consumes* the `Option`, and passes ownership of the `Vec` to the closure. The call to `last` in the closure returns a reference into the `Vec`. The referred-to item is cloned, which creates a new item that is distinct from the `Vec`. When the `Vec` is dropped after the closure, there are no references into it that could cause a problem.

The types of `m` differ between your cases. The first and second cases would return a `Option<&u32>` if they both worked. The third case returns a `Option<u32>`.

There's a fourth option as well:

```
let r = make_vec();
let m = r.as_ref().and_then(|v| v.last());
```

This converts the `Option<T>` into an `Option<&T>`. This new `Option` references the *original* option and can be consumed by the call to `and_then`.

There's a fifth option as well! ^_^ If you are just going to throw away the vector, you can be a bit more explicit about the fact that you want to take it anyway:

```
let m = make_vec().and_then(|v| v.pop());
```

> Does clone here actually copy things in memory or will the compiler optimise it to effectively pass the ownership of the vector element back? Since this was u32s throughout, I was expecting that they would generally be copied instead of referenced.

Optimizing is a tricky thing, and the only true answer is to look at the optimized output. **I** would assume that anything that is `Copy` and is "small enough" wouldn't really cause a problem. However, I might look at making my code as semantic as possible in order to help the optimizer. I'd probably try to have the `pop` variant if that code is what you mean.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's passed to nothing. The vec is passed into the closure and then dropped.

Comment: @Steven great point! That was really sloppy wording on my part. How does it read now?

Comment: Comparing your explanation of (1), in (2) why doesn't the ownership of the `Option` pass to the `and_then` call, and then the ownership of the vector pass to the closure?

Comment: @PeterHall haha, I was just noticing that and changed it accordingly!

Comment: Ah, you changed your answer while I was replying. Does `clone` here actually copy things in memory or will the compiler optimise it to effectively pass the ownership of the vector element back?  Since this was `u32`s throughout, I was expecting that they would generally be copied instead of referenced.

Comment: @PeterHall updated with a weak attempt to answer that. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful